# Cannot show the action buttons on an event preview. ¿Something I forgot?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-calendar

I'm making an angular app with a component that shows events in a calendar, so I've decided to use angular-calendar for the view. In the moth view there's an option that shows all events of a day and allow to modify/delete the event. However, i'm not able to show the action buttons, so i can't show the corresponding dialogs.

Angular-calendar example screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZv67.png)

My app example screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXiQX.png)

To implement this I've followed the [example](https://angular-calendar.com/#/kitchen-sink) and added a CalendarEventAction[] with the modify and delete options and added to my example event like this (I've not included all the code):

calendar.component.ts:

```
actions: CalendarEventAction[] = [
{
  label: '<i class="fas fa-fw fa-pencil-alt"></i>',
  a11yLabel: 'Edit',
  onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
    this.inspectEvent(event)
  },
},
{
  label: '<i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash-alt"></i>',
  a11yLabel: 'Delete',
  onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
    this.events = this.events.filter((iEvent) => iEvent !== event);
    this.inspectEvent(event)
  },
}];

events: CalendarEvent[] = [
{
  start: startOfDay(new Date()),
  title: 'First event',
  end: endOfDay(new Date()),
  actions: this.actions,
}];

dayClicked({ date, events }: { date: Date; events: CalendarEvent[] }): void {
if (isSameMonth(date, this.viewDate)) {
  if (
    (isSameDay(this.viewDate, date) && this.activeDayIsOpen === true) ||
    events.length === 0
  ) {
    this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
  } else {
    this.activeDayIsOpen = true;
  }
  this.viewDate = date;
}
```

}

calendar.component.html:

```
<div class="calendarView" [ngSwitch]="view">
    
        <mwl-calendar-month-view *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Month" 
        [activeDayIsOpen]="activeDayIsOpen" 
        [refresh]="refresh" 
        [viewDate]="viewDate" 
        [events]="events" 
        (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)" 
        (eventClicked) ="inspectEvent($event.event)">
        </mwl-calendar-month-view>
    
        <mwl-calendar-week-view *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Week" 
        [refresh]="refresh" 
        [viewDate]="viewDate" 
        [events]="events" 
        (eventClicked) ="inspectEvent($event.event)">
        </mwl-calendar-week-view>
    
        <mwl-calendar-day-view *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Day" 
        [refresh]="refresh" 
        [viewDate]="viewDate" 
        [events]="events" 
        (eventClicked) ="inspectEvent($event.event)">
        </mwl-calendar-day-view>
    
</div>
```

However, the buttons doesn't appear and I don't know whats the problem.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your action buttons are FontAwesome Icon buttons, you need to import the CSS for the buttons to work.

You probably forgot to add [FontAwesome](http://fontawesome.com/) inside the `head` tag of your `index.html`.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
</head>
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwbxvy?file=src/index.html)

**Result:**

[image]